# Can you type a field in an interface to a Component that implements another interface?

Tags: angular, typescript, interface, components

I have created an interface for my components to implement so that each component created for this type have the same fields. I then have another interface which has a field that requires this type of component.

I have created these interfaces and setup the corresponding components and objects yet I still get the following error:

```
Type 'typeof MyComponent' cannot be assigned to type 'ComponentShouldImplementThis<T>'. Property 'someField' is missing in type 'typeof MyComponent'.
```

My interfaces:

```
export interface ComponentShouldImplementThis<T> {
  someField: string;
}

export interface ContainsFieldComponentInterface<T> {
  component: ComponentShouldImplementThis<T>;
}
```

My Component:

```
@Component({
 selector: 'mycomponent',
 template: '<div>Hello</div>'
})
export class MyComponent implements ComponentShouldImplementThis<any> {
  someField: string;
  constructor(){}
}
```

My Object that yells at me:

```
let implementedInterface: ContainsFieldComponentInterface = {
  component: MyComponent
}
```

`someField` satisfies the IDE when implementing ComponentShouldImplementThis but the interface for having a component that implements it, does not like.

Something I got to get angular compiled was doing an instance of the component instead:

```
let implementedInterface: ContainsFieldComponentInterface = {
  component: new MyComponent
}
```

But this causes some other issues downstream. Is this the correct implementation? Not sure where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a type in `angular/core` that represents Component:
https://angular.io/api/core/Type

Usage:

```
export interface ContainsFieldComponentInterface<T> {
  component: Type<ComponentShouldImplementThis<T>>;
}
```

Why is your type information not working? You probably remember that classes in JS/TS are Functions (or constructor functions) that create objects. You specify the type of the created object in your interface (verifying that the created object will have all the properties of a class). If want to narrow down the possible constructor functions you have to create another type:

```
type OfSpecificType<T> = {
   new (...args: any[]): T
}
```

This signature means that calling a function of `OfSpecificType` type will return the type `T`.

So your interface will end up looking like:

```
export interface ContainsFieldComponentInterface<T> {
  component: OfSpecificType<ComponentShouldImplementThis<T>>;
}
```

but it's the same as using `angular/core`'s `Type<T>`